# .filter() doesn't filter the array of Autocomplete using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, autocomplete

I've been reading a lot and implementing a lot of different possible solutions to this problem but none has worked for me. What happens is that .filter() doesn't filter the suggestions Array of my Autocomplete. The error I am getting is .filter() is not a function which I solve by adding .toString(), but I believe I shouldn't need to use this method as I've seen other examples very similiar to mine that work without applying .toString()

filter:

```
const AutoComplete = (props) => {
    // console.log("suggestions:", props.suggestions);
    // console.log("search:", props.search);
    return (
        <div className="autocomplete_list">
            {props.suggestions
                .filter(name => props.search === '' ||
name.toString().includes(props.search.toLowerCase()))
                // .filter(({ name }) => name.indexOf(props.search.toLowerCase()) > -1)
                .map((value) => {
                    console.log('Value:', value.name);
                    return (
                        <div
                            className="autocomplete_item"
                            onClick={() => props.updateSeach(value.name)}
                            key={value.name}
                            tabIndex="0"
                        >
                            <span>{value.name}</span>
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
    )}
```

Data that I am passing:

```
export const InputOptions = [
    {
        "name": 'Jonathan',
        "country": 'Mexico',
    },
    {
        "name": 'Aldo Ova',
        "country": 'Mexico',
    },
    {
        "name": 'Susana',
        "country": 'Mexico',
    },
    {
        "name": 'Diabetes',
        "country": 'Mexico',
    },
    {
        "name": 'Diablo 2',
        "country": 'Mexico',
    },
    {
        "name": 'Comunist',
        "country": 'Mexico',
    },
]
```

As you can see above, I have tried .indexOf and .includes and in both cases I had to apply .toString() to compile the program but when typing on the input the suggestions List doesn't get filter.

Any ideas will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that you compare 2 strings but only one of was convert to lower case, and other error is not destructuring your props, its recommended as good practice, and the last in your filter method you compare name directly but remember in those types of methods as `map`, `filter`, `find` you receive in the first parameter a entry object, you need destructuring that too.

Look this is your code working with some changes:

```
export const AutoComplete = ({ search, suggestions, updateSeach }) => {
  return (
    <div className='autocomplete_list'>
      {suggestions
        .filter(({ name }) => search === '' || name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))
        .map(value => (
          <div className='autocomplete_item' onClick={() => updateSeach(value.name)} key={value.name} tabIndex='0'>
            <span>{value.name}</span>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

It works for me, this is example of how its called. Only change the function `updateSeach`

```
<AutoComplete search={search} suggestions={suggestions} updateSeach={() => {}}/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did add the 2nd toLowerCase function and it worked fine. Regarding the destructuring, thank you very much for that too!